# AngularJS run compile directives after $http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the $scope of my controller, I have an object called myObject that is to be populated by a $http.get(...).

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    this.myObject={};  //object to be loaded by $http.get

    //We initiate the request to load myObject.
    $http({
        url: '/myurl',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(result){
           this.myObject = result.data;
    }, function(data, status){});

}]);
```

In the HTML view, there are a lot of directives that depend on myObject, and will return errors such as "Cannot read property 'xxx' of null" if it is run before the $http.get returns a response.

How would you go about pausing the directives being run before this.myObject is loaded?

Comment: it depends on how the directive is using the data. Would be nice if you post the directive code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delay the execution of directive by wrapping it with `ng-if`. You can do something like below.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-if="vm.loadingComplete">
  <your-directive your-data="vm.myObject"></your-directive>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var vm = this; 

    // notice I have create variable vm and cached this
    // if not done so, you cannot use this.something inside nested functions
    // as this would mean something else there

    vm.myObject={};  //object to be loaded by $http.get
    vm.loadingComplete = false;

    //We initiate the request to load myObject.
    $http({
        url: '/myurl',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(result){
       // you had a issue here before
       // this.myObject is not same as this.myObject outside this function
       vm.myObject = result.data;
       vm.loadingComplete = result;
    }, function(data, status){});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume your directive is 'testDir',

```
app.directive('testDir', function(){
 return {
            restrict: "AE",
            transclude: true,
            replace: false,
            //templateUrl: "/views/api_status_chart.html",
            scope: {
                myData: '=' // this is your data from the controller
            },
            link: function (scope, element, args) {

                  initializeDirective function(){
                       // wrap all your functionality inside this function
                  }

                  scope.$watch('myData', function(newVal){
                       // if new value is not null do your all computation
                       if(newVal != null && newVal.length > 0){
                              initializeDirective();
                       }
                  });
            }
});

<test-dir my-data="myObject "> </test-dir>
```

**Concept**

Do all your functionality only when the data is not null. Otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

use `ngIf` directive which comes with angular js and validate the `myObject` in the html template before using it .

```
`<div ng-if="myObject!=== null"> <!-- set myObject = null by default in controller -->
   <!-- use myObject's values to generate DOM -->
</div>`
```

Since angular works on two way binding , whenever `myObject` is set to a value, angular will evaluate `ng-if` directive on the html template.

[ngIf
- directive in module ng](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)